# How to generate a index-app / file with dgeni

Tags: javascript, angularjs, documentation-generation

I need to document a existing AngularJS (1.6.x + Webpack2 + es6-modules) project and would like to stick to a well known way to document it. For example like the way AngularJS itself is documented.

I struggle hard to setup dgeni. 
I found a blog post [Documenting your Angular app using Dgeni in 10 easy steps](https://toddmotto.com/documenting-angular-dgeni)
 and a [three year old example project](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/dgeni-angular).

```
'use strict';

var path = require('canonical-path');
const {Dgeni, Package} = require('dgeni');

var hm = new Package('documentation', [
  require('dgeni-packages/ngdoc'),
  require('dgeni-packages/nunjucks')
])
  .config(function (log, readFilesProcessor, writeFilesProcessor) {
  log.level = 'info';
  readFilesProcessor.basePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
  readFilesProcessor.sourceFiles = [
    {
      include: 'src/main/javascript/**/*.js',
      basePath: 'src/main/javascript'
    },
  ];
  writeFilesProcessor.outputFolder = 'docs/generated';
});
var dgeni = new Dgeni([hm]);

dgeni.generate().then(done);

function done() {
  console.log('done');
}
```

That generates some documentation snippets, but I am missing the part that plumbs it together, some kind of index page or navigation. In the blog post there is
[some example angular app](https://toddmotto.com/documenting-angular-dgeni#creating-our-index-page)
to generate a documentation web-app, but as all the other parts needed a lot of manual intervention to get them working, I don't want to use a most likely half-finished blog tutorial as the base and 
would rather like some easy to use templates for a index app that are provided and updated as a package.

Do I miss something or is every single ordinary configuration step with dgeni a hard job to figure out? I just need some kind of index.

Answer (score 0):

I created an indexPageProcessor that gathers the information and renders it to a index page.

## Index Page Processor

```
'use strict';
const _ = require('lodash');
const changeCase = require('change-case');

module.exports = indexPageProcessor;

function indexPageProcessor() {
  return {
    $runAfter: ['paths-computed'],
    $runBefore: ['rendering-docs'],
    $process: process
  };

  function process(docs) {
    const types = {};
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
      types[doc.docType] = types[doc.docType] || [];
      const docData = buildDocData(doc);
      types[doc.docType].push(docData);
    });
    const typeList = [];
    Object.keys(types).forEach((typeName) => {
      typeList.push({
        type: typeName,
        items: types[typeName]
      });
    });

    docs.push({
      baseName: 'index',
      name: 'index',
      template: 'index.template.md',
      outputPath: 'README.md',
      types: typeList
    });
  }
}

function buildDocData(doc) {
  const splitName = doc.name.split('.');
  const stateName = _.camelCase(splitName);
  let displayName = doc.name;
  if (['directive', 'component'].indexOf(doc.docType) >= 0)
    displayName = changeCase.param(doc.name);

  return {
    name: doc.name,
    displayName: displayName,
    stateName: stateName,
    type: doc.docType,
    description: doc.description,
    outputPath: doc.outputPath,
    url: doc.path,
  };
}
```

## Markdown Index Page Template

```
# Angular Documentation
{%- if doc.types %}
{%- for type in doc.types %}

# {$ type.type $}
{%- for item in type.items %}
* [{$ item.displayName $}]({$ item.outputPath $})<br>
  {%- if item.description %}
  {$ item.description | firstParagraph $}
  {%- endif -%}{% endfor -%}

{% endfor -%}
{% endif -%}
```

## Main Javascript for Documentation Generation

```
'use strict';

const path = require('canonical-path');
const {Dgeni, Package} = require('dgeni');

const hm = new Package('documentation', [
  require('dgeni-markdown')
])
  .processor(require('./indexPage'))
  .config(function (log, readFilesProcessor, writeFilesProcessor, templateFinder) {
    log.level = 'warn';
    readFilesProcessor.basePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
    readFilesProcessor.sourceFiles = [
      {
        include: 'src/main/javascript/**/*.js',
        basePath: 'src/main/javascript'
      },
    ];
    templateFinder.templateFolders.unshift(path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates'));
    writeFilesProcessor.outputFolder = 'docs/generated';
  });
const dgeni = new Dgeni([hm]);

module.exports = () => dgeni.generate().then(done);

dgeni.generate().then(done);

function done() {
  console.log('Generated documentation.');
}
```

I use a markdown output, regenerate that during each build, so that we can browse the latest documentation easly within gitlab.